# De que manera puedo modificar este código

Tags: javascript

Tengo esta linea:

```js
   var _from = location.href.split('/'); // Permite obtener la ruta del archivo actual y convertirla en array separados por "/"
    _from = _from[_from.length - 1].replace('.html','').replace('index_',''); // filtramos el contenido del array y extraemos el nombre del archivo

      $.ajax({url: "http://digital12.xegmenta.com:3000/weather/api/"+_from,
      success: function(result){
      $("#content-text").html(result.name);
      $("#content-text2").html(Math.round(result.main.temp));
      $("#content-text3").attr("class", "fondo_" + result.weather[0].icon);
      $("#myVideo").attr("src", result.weather[0].icon +  ".mp4");

}});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function EnaviarDatos() {

                var cedula = $('#cedula').val();
                var nombre1 = $('#nombre1').val();
                var nombre2 = $('#nombre2').val();
                var apellido1 = $('#apellido1').val();
                var apellido2 = $('#apellido2').val();
                var historia = $('#historia').val();
                var cedula = $('#cedula').val();
                var expedicion = $('#expedicion').val();
                var nombrecompleto = nombre1.trim().concat(' '+ nombre2.trim(), ' '+ apellido1.trim(),' '+ apellido2.trim());
                location.href = '@Url.Action("File", "CAPBAS")?id=' + cedula.trim() + '&expedicion=' + expedicion.trim() + '&nombre=' + nombrecompleto.trim() + '&historia= ' + historia.trim();
            }
```

Comment: Amigo, es que tengo esto de la siguiente manera `mira el código arriba completo.` @HeinerSaid, como lo puedo acomodar ahí ?